# Полифилл для JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Какой лучше использовать полифилл для современных свойств и методов JavaScript типа classList, insertAjacentHTML, addEventListener, *ElementSibling с поддержкой IE8+

Comment: гугл в помощь

Comment: Я уже смотрел некоторые варианты на Гитхабе. Например, есть https://github.com/termi/ES5-DOM-SHIM, который в свою очередь основан на других полифиллах: https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim, https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim, https://github.com/Raynos/DOM-shim Также на Гитхабе есть целый список полифиллов, например: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Comment: и чем вам всё это не подходит ?

Comment: Думаю, может есть лучше варианты? Стоит просто проблема оптимального выбора. Чтобы ещё и на большинстве мобильных браузеров работало.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри проект [Autopolyfiller](https://github.com/azproduction/autopolyfiller). Отличная идея это автоматизировать.

Comment: Идея хорошая автоматизировать поиск полифиллов для определённого круга браузеров, но вопрос немного не об этом. Всё же остановил свой выбор на этом полифилле: https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim Хотя, если честно, пора завязывать с "восьмёркой"

Comment: Поддерживать или не поддерживать браузер, надо принимать решение на каждом проекте отдельно по статистике, например >0,5%.

По Autopolyfiller к сожалению поторопился с рекомендацией, для на addEventListener нет полифилла, есть все эти http://github.com/jonathantneal/polyfill/tree/master/source и можно добавить что надо.

Еще рекомендую посмотреть выступление "Components NOW!" Михаил Давыдов, Яндекс https://vimeo.com/90836495

Answer (score 1):

Вот же есть прекрасный сайт [You Might Not Need Jquery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/). Там все отлично сгруппировано. Например:

jQuery

```
$(el).hide();
```

JavaScript, IE8+

```
el.style.display = 'none';
```